# Chrome Extension save temporary file

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, save, filesystems, temporary

I have a Chrome Extension that needs to temporarily save a few (two or three) PNG images.

What I am currently doing is getting the image data URI, and saving this in localstorage. But I know that this is not a very good way of doing it, especially as some of the images are bigger than 5mb, and I therefore have difficulty storing them.

I've seen a few extensions (Single File Extension, and a few others) that have the ability of "saving" a temporary file in the extension folder, but I am not sure how I can achieve this.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Use the Storage API: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_storage

Comment: Filesystem api: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HTML5 FileSystem APIs](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/) to save your images to a target directory.

If your option is not limited to chrome extensions, you can write an chrome app, and then [chrome.fileSystem](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem) is available to you.